# Can you copy weight data to other side of mesh (Blender 3.2)?

Tags: weight-painting, mirror

Is it possible to mirror your weight painting **AFTER** already painting one side of your mesh?

My armature was paired with automatic weights and I adjusted the RIGHT side of my mesh, assuming X symmetry would automatically reflect on the opposite sides.  Evidently I assumed wrong and now only the Right side of my mesh has the correct weights while the other still has the automatic weights.

Is there a way for me to copy the weight painting of the Right side of my mesh over to the left so that the weights are consistent?  Or will I need to bite the bullet and paint the left side by hand?

Thank you for your help!

[image: FIGURE A]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can copy weights over quite easily, providing the mesh is truly symmetrical. All you need to do is:

1. Select your Left Arm's vertex group, click the little down arrow and choose "Copy Vertex Group". Now we will mirror this duplicate group to the right side.
2. Now select the new duplicated group, click the down arrow again and choose "Mirror vertex group".
3. All that's left to do is to simply rename this freshly mirrored group to be the **same name** as your **original Right Arm vertex group**-- however, since two groups can't both have the same name, you'll need to delete the original group or rename it to something else first.

[image: Mirror Weight Paint in Blender]

Comment: By LEFT or RIGHT, I meant your character's physical LEFT or RIGHT arm in relation to their head, not screen left or right, as described in your post (which is what we see when looking in a mirror). But the principle of mirroring remains the same. :-)